# Separating Python bytes array starting on \x with regEx

Tags: python, regex, hex, aes

Trying to Encrypt every 26 char length block like so, first turn it into an array of bytes then use regex to find every \x in the bytearray and afterwards encrypt it with AES.

```
import re
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes


key=get_random_bytes(16)    
generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CCM)
crypt=""

textHex="87315a69020000006400110400096d617274696e657433010882848b962430486c03010b0504000100002a01042f010432040c121860dd06001018010100dd160050f20101000050f20201000050f20201000050f202"
textBlocks=re.findall('.{1,26}',textHex)

for i in range(0,len(textBlocks)):

    textBlocks[i]=bytes.fromhex(textBlocks[i])

    textBlocks2=re.findall('.+?(?=\\\x)', textBlocks[i])

    for j in range(0,len(textBlocks2):
       crypt += generator.encrypt(textBlocks2[j])
```

The  problem is that the regex doesnt recognise the \x00
[image]

also while this regex works on the [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) , python displays the following error

*SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-9: truncated \xXX escape*

Comment: why do you use `javascript` in your online regex tool,when you are using `python`? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just getting the last `\x00`

you can use the following regex for **javascript**: `.+?(?=\\\x|$)`

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/4ieyDq/1

if what you want is a **python** regex then you can use: `.+?(?=\\x|$)`

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/gvWxDI/1/

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-9: truncated \xXX escape Is still being displayed, any idea why?